# Instagram API only displays first item in foreach loop

Tags: php, instagram-api

Looking for some help with this. I've created an instagram gallery using the api. When I print_r the json output I get the full array with all 12 posts, but when I echo out the contents in the foreach loop I'm only getting the first post in the list displayed. Thanks for any help. hopping it's just something silly I have missed.

This is the code I have:

```
<?php
    $access_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $photo_count  = 12;

    $json_link = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?";
    $json_link .= "access_token={$access_token}&count={$photo_count}";

    $json = file_get_contents($json_link);
    $obj  = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
    //print_r($json);
?>
<div id="instafeed">
    <?php
        foreach($obj['data'] as $post){

            $pic_text     = $post['caption']['text'];
            $pic_link     = $post['link'];
            $pic_src      = str_replace("http://", "https://", $post['images']['low_resolution']['url']);
            $pic_time     = date('d-m-Y H:i', $post['caption']['created_time']);
            $pic_icon_src = $post['user']['profile_picture'];
            $pic_handle   = $post['user']['username'];
            ?>
            <div class="social-block">
                <a href="<?php echo $pic_link; ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php echo $pic_text; ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $pic_src; ?>" title="<?php echo $pic_text; ?>" width="100% " height="auto">
                    <div class="insta-acc">
                        <span class="insta-icon"><img src="<?php echo $pic_icon_src; ?>" title="Uk Pro Surf on Instagram"></span>
                        <div>
                            <span class="insta-handle">@<?php echo $pic_handle; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="insta-text"><p><?php echo $pic_text; ?></p></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: can we see the json

Comment: You could be breaking your html as you are not encoding the values you echo out. Are the items present in the source code of the generated html?

Comment: We need to see the JSON if you want us to help you.

Comment: A sample JSON is here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/ Click to RESPONSE.

Comment: Tested your code with https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/ sample JSON, it's not valid and after fixing it json_decode returns 2 objects or 2 arrays (splitting at "videos"). so the first array has all your chosen values but the second doesn't. Maybe this could help, can't figure out more without the actual json you're running.

Comment: I think @yasoh might be on to something. It appears to break after the first item as this is a video media type. Thanks all, just about fixed this now.